# How to write Multiple If-Else with Return Integer value

Tags: python-3.x

```
def score():
    edu = df.dummy
    if edu == 1:
        score= 10
    elif edu == 2:
        score= 30
    elif edu == 3:
        score= 80
    elif edu == 4:
        score= 100
    elif edu == 5:
        score= 125
    elif edu == 6:
        score= 150
    elif edu == 7:
        score= 200
    else: return score
```

> Error Occured : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>   How to return a integer value with Multiple if else conditions

Comment: What is `edu`? What is `df`?

Comment: what's inside edu?

Comment: Hi Mureinik, df is a Data Frame with dummy as a column of integer type and I am storing that value in edu(like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

Comment: You are comparing entire `pandas.Series` with single int value that is why you are getting above error.

Comment: You want to return score right?

Comment: yes i want to return score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def edu_score():
    edu = df.dummy
    edu_score=[]
    for i in edu:
        if(i == 1):
            score = 10
        elif(i == 2):
            score = 30
        elif(i == 3):
            score = 80
        elif(i == 4):
            score = 100
        elif(i == 5):
            score = 125
        elif(i == 6):
            score = 150
        elif(i == 7):
            score = 200
        edu_score.append(score)
    return edu_score
```

Here is your answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if edu is bigger than 7, score is not assigned to any value. So you cannot return score.

And, you can try `df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['type'])`.

Comment: edu consists of 9 values from 0 to 8

Comment: The problem is about score. Not edu. If edu is 0 or 8, you dont assign any value to "score" and you try to return score.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear the else statement and you're done

```
def scores():
    score=0
    edu = df.dummy

    if edu == 1:
        score= 10
    elif edu == 2:
        score= 30
    elif edu == 3:
        score= 80
    elif edu == 4:
        score= 100
    elif edu == 5:
        score= 125
    elif edu == 6:
        score= 150
    elif edu == 7:
        score= 200
    return score
```

Comment: The code u gave works fine but it takes edu == 7 only

Comment: oh! I accidentally put the line `edu=7` in the function. Wait, I'll edit.

Comment: @KranthiKumarReddy Try now

Answer (score 0):

```
def score(edu):
    if edu == 1:
        score= 10
    elif edu == 2:
        score= 30
    elif edu == 3:
        score= 80
    elif edu == 4:
        score= 100
    elif edu == 5:
        score= 125
    elif edu == 6:
        score= 150
    elif edu == 7:
        score= 200
    else:
        score=0
return score
```

now, when you are calling the function, pass the dataframe as
score(df.dummy).